# How can I use a range as input for an external command without deleting it?

Tags: external-command, range

I'm executing an external command that takes as input a range of lines within my file.

```
:'<,'>!copy_stuff
```

Running this runs `copy_stuff` correctly with the currently selected visual range (and it also works fine with any other range). However, since `copy_stuff` doesn't write anything to stdout, it also deletes that range.

Is there any way to pass a range as input to a command without deleting the lines in that range?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:write` for this:

```
:'<,'>w !copy_stuff
```

For more details, see [`:help :write_c`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Aw_c):

> Execute {cmd} with [range] lines as standard input
>               (note the space in front of the '!').

Comment: Hah! Of course it was this simple... Amazing how you forget about this stuff. And here I was defining user commands for it...

Comment: @filbranden Oh I definitely know *that* feeling.

Answer (score 2):

[Rich's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22714/18609) using `:'<,'>w !copy_stuff` is the right answer!

---

One alternative is to use the [`system()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html?#system%28%29) function.

You can pass it a string as input, which you can get from a register that captures the text in your range.

It's convenient to define a user command for this purpose, since then you can easily pass it a range.

For example, with your `copy_stuff`:

```
function! CopyStuff(line1, line2)
    let save_reg = getreg('"')
    let save_type = getregtype('"')
    silent execute a:line1 ',' a:line2 'y'
    call system('copy_stuff', @")
    call setreg('"', save_reg, save_type)
endfunction

command! -range=% -bar CopyStuff call CopyStuff(<line1>, <line2>)
```

The first two lines and last line of the function body are saving and restoring the default register (so that it doesn't affect your put commands.)

The third line yanks the range (passed as arguments) into the default register.

Finally, the `system()` call passes the contents of the default register as input for the external command.

The user-defined command is using `-range=%`, which allows it to take a range, and defaults to the whole buffer if one isn't passed (you can omit the `=%` part if you prefer to default to the current line.)

The `<line1>` and `<line2>` placeholders are replaced with the first and last line of the range when the command is executed.

The `-bar` is there because it's good to have it, always, to be able to put another command on the same line after a `|`. (Only exception if you want to handle `|`s yourself in arguments, but that's seldom the case.)

Invoke it with:

```
:CopyStuff
```

Or from visual mode:

```
:'<,'>CopyStuff
```

See [`:help :command`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html?#%3Acommand) for more options available for user-defined commands (such as arguments).