# MacVim: how to prevent :[range]!say to remove text?

Tags: command-line, range

I am writing some prose and I find very useful to hear what I wrote from an external voice. I found the command `say` which I guess is only available on MacOsX (perhaps other OS have some equivalent).

However, by doing `:[range]!say` the selected text is removed from my buffer.

How to prevent that?

Answer (score -1):

`:help :range` *filters* the given range of lines through an external command. The whole point of that feature is *precisely* to replace the given lines by the output of the external command so using it and expecting the given lines to not be changed makes no sense: you use it *to* change the given range of lines.

Moreover, `$ man say` doesn't output text so there is no point in using it as a filter.

You don't actually want a filter. What you want is [the ability to pass an arbitrary selection or range of lines to an external command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22713/how-can-i-use-a-range-as-input-for-an-external-command-without-deleting-it).

The simplest way being `:help :write_c`:

```
:[range]w !say
```

Comment: Hundred times? It looks like only one. And mathematically 1 < 100. Please, update your answer because that part is very wrong (other than being passive aggressive that may violate the code of conduct of this site).